# sharelatex compile different pdfs with different operating systems

Tags: pstricks, windows, mac, sharelatex

I've been compiling a project with ShareLaTeX in Windows and the PDF file is OK, but when I compile the same project with ShareLateX on my MacOS the Pspictures environments using the Pstricks package only typesets empty boxes. I use the XeLaTeX compiler in ShareLaTeX in both cases. What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not the clearest on ShareLaTeX but I thought its selling point was that the compilation was online and not local so I'm not sure how it could be different between operating systems.  Might it just be the use of different PDF viewers or web browsers?

Comment: Welcome! What you are describing is essentially impossible unless ShareLaTeX have updated their TeX installation after you compiled on Windows and before you compiled on OS X (I'm assuming you aren't really using MacOS) and that update broke the code. This is possible but unlikely and it would break the code on Windows, too, from then on until it was fixed. It sounds more like you've added `draft` to you class options or to the package options for `graphicx`. However, since you've not provided a minimal example, we can only guess.

Comment: I suppose that you have the `draft` option enabled. Then all PSTricks environments are replaced by an empty rectangle.

Comment: Is there any news here?